# Not able to send automated mails by task scheduler and python

Tags: email, outlook, taskbar

I use a *python script* to send mails. The script runs a VBA macro.

I'm scheduling the python script to run at a particular time.

#### Configuration

My trust settings in Outlook has all macros enabled.
I'm running the task with highest priority too.

#### Problem

I am able to send mails if I run the script manually.
However, when I try to run it via [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler), mails are not being sent.

Comment: Have you tried running other software / scripts with the scheduler? Does this work?

Comment: Hi, yes. I've tried to run other python scripts. It works great. 
Ex : - I have a script in which I perform operations on excel application. TS runs the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different *scheduler* and see if this works.

For example [*Splinterware* system scheduler](https://www.splinterware.com/products/scheduler.html).

Trying a different scheduler can help you figure out if the problem is

- a **setting** in the *scheduler* (like not having the password entered)
- or in your **Python script** (which would affect all schedulers)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to send emails from Outlook automatically without the use of Task Scheduler. It is outlined neatly [here](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/send-email-outlook-reminders-fires/).

It uses recurring reminders, so Outlook must be kept running at all times (but the macro is only executed when the reminder fires).